# What is the most effective way to find an already existing Google Sheets chart type in code (Google Scripts)?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

For the life of me, I can't find any documentation from google, or answers online that really help me understand and answer my question of how to use `getChartType()`.

I'm trying to use Google Scripts to access a specific Google Spreadsheet that has multiple charts already there, a pie chart and a bar graph. All I want to do is figure out, in the code on Google Scripts, how to find the chart type. From my research, `getChartType()` seemed to be the best option, but any sample code I have found throws errors.

If there is a better or simpler way to find what type of chart an EmbeddedChart is, then I'm completely open to suggestions. If `getChartType()` is the best option, please help me understand how specifically to use it.

I've tried these sources, and more:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-pie-chart-builder

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#chartwrapperobject

Comment: getChartType() seems to be broken. You can only use getType() but not getChartType, I've tried it as wel with my limited apps script Chart knowledge. What result are you expecting to be returned?

Comment: Hmm, interesting. That would kinda explain some of my confusion. I'm trying to get a string or something I can work with, like: `var chart1 = charts[0].getType()` returning something like chart1 containing `"PIE"` or something along those lines. I just need to define the already existing chart types to check if they are the right type of chart, all from the script side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after searching further through the Google Apps Script documentation, I kinda put two and two together and worked out how to get an existing chart type. You have to nest some functions, which is what I wasn't fully understanding at first. To get an existing chart type I have this code:

```
var charts = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('sheeturl').getActiveSheet().getCharts();

var chart_types = [];
  for(i = 0; i < charts.length; i++)
    if(charts[i]){chart_types.push(charts[i].modify().getChartType());}

Logger.log(chart_types);
```

This returned (in my case for a pie and bar chart): `[PIE, BAR]`. The key for me in this case was using `.modify().getChartType()` in conjunction with `.getCharts()`